# Spring CorsRegistry seems to ignore some protocols

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ionic-framework

I am developing a hybrid Ionic app and having problem with CORS.

I have got into CORS problems often enough, and I believe this has something to do with Spring security.

Since Ionic's iOS app runs on ionic://localhost, my backend(Spring) was not accepting any request from the iOS app. See the browser console errors below:

```
Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/forum/categories due to access control checks.
```

This was sort of expected. Technically, all I need to do should be adding this origin to my Spring application as below:

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("ionic://localhost")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH");
```

However, this did not resolve the CORS problem for me. I am stilling getting the same CORS error message in the browser console.

I also tried allowedOrigins("*"), but it did not work as well.

Now I am suspecting if Spring does not allow certain protocols although it has been added in 'allowedOrigins'.

Has anyone come across this issue? Any insight will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. This is me being stupid and trying to hit Production instance when all the CORS changes were made in Dev.

Spring CORS configuration DOES support any protocol, since it is really String comparison in the backend and does not care about protocol at all.